# How to create pagination with PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

how to create pagination using mysql pdo and php
im create code like this, but got some error msg

```
<?php 
$halaman = 2; //batasan halaman
$page = isset($_GET['halaman'])? (int)$_GET["halaman"]:1;
$mulai = ($page>1) ? ($page * $halaman) - $halaman : 0;
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kategori");
$result->execute();
$total = $result->fetchAll();
$pages = ceil(count($total/$halaman)); 
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategori LIMIT $mulai, $halaman");
    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->fetchAll();
    $no =$mulai+1;
?>
<?php foreach ($data as $value): ?>
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>                  
      <td><?php echo $value['nama_kat']; ?></td> 
<?php               
  endforeach;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to pagination:

```
<?php
$limit = 2;
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM kategori";

$s = $db->query($query);
$total_results = $s->fetchColumn();
$total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}



$starting_limit = ($page-1)*$limit;
$show  = "SELECT * FROM kategori ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,?";

$r = $db->prepare($show);
$r->execute([$starting_limit, $limit]);

while($res = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
?>
<h4><?php echo $res['id'];?></h4>
<p><?php echo $res['nama_kat'];?></p>
<hr>
<?php
endwhile;


for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>

<a href='<?php echo "?page=$page"; ?>' class="links"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Just try things like that. You will learn that very soon. Amend that according to your needs. And beware that its vulnerable to Sql injection don't use it in your production site.