# Bindparam is not working for my pagination script

Tags: php, mysql

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792931/how-to-create-pagination-with-pdo-php) script and because is possible to be vulnerable to sql injection I tried to bindparam **starting_limit** variable but is not working. Here is my code:

```
include("include/config.php");
include("include/functions.php");

$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM tutorials");
$query->execute();
$total_results = $query->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $paglimit);
if (!isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = 1;
    $_GET["page"] = 1;
} else {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
$starting_limit = ($page - 1) * $paglimit;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div class="list-group mt-4 posts-list-custom">
<? $query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM tutorials ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :starting_limit , $paglimit"); $query->bindParam(":starting_limit", $starting_limit); $query->execute(); $result = $query->fetchAll(); foreach($result as $row) { ?>
<a href="<?=$tutorialsroot . str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($row["title"])); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?=$row["title"];?></a>
<? } ?>
</div>
<ul class="pagination mt-3">
<? for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++): ?>
<li class="page-item<? if($page == $_GET["page"]) { echo " active"; }?>"><a href="<?=$tutorialsroot . "?page=" . $page;?>" class="page-link"><?=$page;?></a></li>
<? endfor; ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the error I get:

> Fatal error : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' , 5' at
>   line 1' in /home/rnywimzk/public_html/tutorials_subdomain/index.php:38
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/rnywimzk/public_html/tutorials_subdomain/index.php(38):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/rnywimzk/public_html/tutorials_subdomain/index.php on line 38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1/** I don't think this is a good synthax :

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM tutorials 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :starting_limit , $paglimit");
```

You probably meant :

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM tutorials 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $paglimit OFFSET :starting_limit");
```

**2/** You have to specify the `PDOStatement::bindParam` `$data_type` argument which by default is `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

( http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

In your case `starting_limit` should have the type `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Change :

```
$query->bindParam(":starting_limit", $starting_limit);
```

To :

```
$query->bindParam(":starting_limit", $starting_limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: It works now, thanks. Is not first time when I use bindparam and always I did without PDO::PARAM_INT. I have to read the link from php with the docs to understand why exactly.