# How to create safe (avoid SQL injection) pagination using PHP and PDO and prepared statement?

Tags: php, security, pdo, sql-injection

I was searching for creating PDO pagination and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793133/348589), which vulnerable for SQL injection.

I'm wondering about the easiest way to convert this code to be SQL injection safe.

**Update #1**
In my case I want to add optional where statement and order by based on the user input

My code is:

```
<?php
$limit = 2;
$order_by   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'order_by');
$order_dir  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'order_dir');
$query_research_str = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search_str');
$query = "SELECT * FROM kategori";
// If search string
if ($query_research_str) {
    //$dbmanager->where('user_name', '%' . $query_research_str . '%', 'like');
    $query = $query . "where user_name like %".$query_research_str."% ";
}
// If order direction option selected
if ($order_dir) {
    //$dbmanager->orderBy($order_by, $order_dir);
    $query = $query . " order By ".$order_by." ".$order_dir;
}

$s = $db->prepare($query);
$s->execute();
$total_results = $s->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}



$starting_limit = ($page-1)*$limit;
$show  = $query." LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit";

$r = $db->prepare($show);
$r->execute();

while($res = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
?>
<h4><?php echo $res['id'];?></h4>
<p><?php echo $res['nama_kat'];?></p>
<hr>
<?php
endwhile;


for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>

<a href='<?php echo "?page=$page"; ?>' class="links"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: it is generally considered more efficient, especially with large recordsets to use `id between x and y` rather than `limit x,y` - so as you are using the where clause the prepared statement remains safe. I think in mysqli you can use placeholders for the limit clause but not in PDO - so, perhaps the id betwwen method has legs?

Comment: @RamRaider kindly check the updated code. I think now it is more complicated and I need a help :)

Comment: @RamRaider - Yes, you can use placeholers for `LIMIT` with PDO. You just have to explicitly set the param as an INT when you bind  it. Passing the params to `execute()` won't work since it then would be treated as a string.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure whether or not it was possible with PDO - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several comments.

```
$order_by   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'order_by');
$order_dir  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'order_dir');
$query_research_str = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search_str');
```

This doesn't make the variables safe. You have not specified any kind of filter as the third argument to filter_input. The docs say:

> If omitted, FILTER_DEFAULT will be used, which is equivalent to FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. This will result in no filtering taking place by default.

In other words, it's exactly as unsafe as using the raw GET variables:

```
$order_by   = $_GET['order_by'];
$order_dir  = $_GET['order_dir'];
$query_research_str = $_GET['search_str'];
```

You should use query parameters for values like your `search_str`, but you can't use query parameters for things that are not SQL values. Like column names and SQL keywords in an ORDER BY clause.

So how to use these safely? **Whitelisting.**

Make an array of columns in your kategori table that are legitimate choices for sorting:

```
$columns = ['user_name', 'create_date'];
```

Then if the input is in this array, it's okay to use. Otherwise use a default.

```
$order_by = 'user_name';
if (array_search($_GET['order_by'], $columns)) {
    $order_by = $_GET['order_by'];
}

$order_dir = 'ASC';
if ($_GET['order_dir'] == 'DESC') {
    $order_dir = 'DESC';
}
```

This way the values can only be those you have pre-validated in your code. There's no SQL injection possible, because if some different value is input, it won't match any of the values your code allows, and therefore the input will be ignored in favor of your defaults.

For the query research string, you should add it to an array of params, and pass that when you `execute()` the query. Don't interpolate unsafe variables directly into your SQL query string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE true";

$params = [];
if ($query_research_str) {
    $query .= " AND user_name LIKE ?";
    $params[] = "%{$query_research_str}%";
}

$query .= " ORDER BY `{$order_by}` {$order_dir}";

$s = $db->prepare($query);
$s->execute($params);
```

I also would have comments about your inefficient paging code. Did you know that before you can call `rowCount()`, your script has to fetch *all* the results? So there's no need to run the query *again* with LIMIT and offset. You already have all the data, so go easy on your database server and just take a slice from the array of results:

```
$rows = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_rows = $s->rowCount();
$page = (int) $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
$offset = ($page-1) * $limit;
$end = min($total_rows, $offset + $limit);

for ($i = $offset; $i < $end; $i++) {
?>
<h4><?php echo $row[$i]['id'];?></h4>
<p><?php echo $row[$i]['nama_kat'];?></p>
<hr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert to integer like `$page = (integer) $_GET['page'];`.
That way if there is any injection code in there it just gets lost in translation.

Comment: what about the other variables?
`$order_by` , `$order_dir` and `$query_research_str`

Comment: `$order_dir` can be requested from the user as an integer - 1 / -1. `$order_by` can also be requested as an integer choice from a list of known columns. Those are the variables specifically dealing with pagination as asked. `$query_research_str` is not a pagination variable and looks like it is being filtered by an undisclosed function. I use the htmlPurifier library to process those.

Answer (score -3):

If you have the ability to put your SQL query as a stored procedure on the SQL server this should take care of your potential SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the question isn't about SQL server. I want to use the PDO

Comment: mySQL allows Stored Procedures too and this is a good way to do it IMO

Comment: Using prepared statements correctly (like the OP asks about in the question) would also take care of any potential SQL injections.

Comment: I'm using PDO sqlite, No chance to use the Stored Procedures

Comment: I'm one of the downvoters. My reason is that it's false that stored procedures "take care of potential SQL injection." Anyone can write unsafe dynamic SQL in stored procedures just as easily as you can in application code.