# Pagination with Bootstrap and PDO

Tags: php, pdo, bootstrap-4

[How to create pagination with PDO PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792931/how-to-create-pagination-with-pdo-php/44793133#44793133)

I cant comment yet so i posted a new question:

My question is, if I use the "ANSWER" on that question with bootstrap, how do I put which button/link is active? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smA0c.png)
here is my code

```
<?php for ($page=1; $page <= $np ; $page++):?> 
<?php if ($_GET['p']==$page) { ?> 
<li class="page-item page-next"> 
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/inbox/'.$page.''; ?>" class="page-link"><?php echo $page; ?> </a> 
</li> 
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `<?php
for ($page=1; $page <= $np ; $page++):?>

<li class="page-item page-next <?php echo ''.$active.''; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/inbox/'.$page.''; ?>" class="page-link"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>
 </li>

<?php endfor; ?>`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an if condition in the for loop that show button/link, it will test if current iteration is same as **$_GET** value.

Workaround :

```
for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>

<a href='<?php echo "?page=$page"; ?>' class="links <?php echo $_GET['page'] === $page ? 'active' : ''  ?>"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: <?php
for ($page=1; $page <= $np ; $page++):?>

<li class="page-item page-next <?php echo ''.$active.''; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/inbox/'.$page.''; ?>" class="page-link"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>
 </li>

<?php endfor; ?>


this is my code.

Comment: `<?php
for ($page=1; $page <= $np ; $page++):?>
<?php 
if ($_GET['p']==$page) {
 $active = 'active';
} else { $active = '';}

?>

<li class="page-item page-next <?php echo ''.$active.''; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/inbox/'.$page.''; ?>" class="page-link"><?php  echo $page; ?>
 </a>
 </li>

<?php endfor; ?>
`

this worked. thanks!

Comment: Nice, if you want simplify you can use ternary like this :
`for ($page=1; $page <= $np ; $page++):?> <li class="page-item page-next <?php echo ''.($_GET['p'] == $page ? $active : '').''; ?>"> <a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/inbox/'.$page.''; ?>" class="page-link"><?php echo $page; ?> </a> </li> <?php endfor; ?>`

Comment: now my problem is, there are like 100pages, so the numbers will go forever. how do i shorten that?

Comment: You should limit this to a range in your for loop, take this workaround :
`$start = ($_GET['p']-5 < 1) ? 0 : $_GET['p']-5;
$end = ($_GET['p']+5 > $np) ? $np : $_GET['p']+5;
for ($page = $start; $page < $end ; $page++) `...

This way we only show 10 items maximum.